# Sorting a list with reference to a class without implementing in java

Tags: java, arraylist

So I get some names from user input and put them into a list that references class Person.

Class person has constructors with getters

```
public String getName(){
    return email;
}
```

But is also has setters with the exceptions so they can't insert a blank or improper name.

```
public void setFullName(String fullName) throws ValidationException{
    validateString(fullName);
    this.fullName = fullName;
}
```

But as it is based on user input, I have x amount of names. What I'm wanting to do is organize them alphabetically so that the first in the list won't necessarily be the first name I entered.

Here is the List and ArrayList that is in a constructor

```
private List<Person> peopleList;
public Contacts(){
    peopleList = new ArrayList<Person>();
}
```

I already know that I can't do

```
List<Person> subList = peopleList.subList(1, peopleList.size());
Collections.sort(subList);
```

Because I get "The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List)" from the Collections.sort

I can't implement a comparable or anything because it won't properly inherit an abstract method from class Person.

So how do I organize the list I have without implementation? If possible.

Comment: Please edit and summarize the main question and lead with with the main part of the question (e.g. put it in the beginning). The title isn't clear enough alone to show what you want to do.  *Then* provide the minimum necessary code examples as background information and context. I had to read all of that stuff just to figure out whether or not I was in a position to answer the question. Your approach will turn off a lot of people who might be able to help you.

Comment: Have you tried using the [other `sort` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))?

Comment: Why can't you make `Person` implement `Comparable` again?

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming is your friend :

```
Collections.sort(peopleList, (Person p1, Person p2) -> p1.getFullName().compareTo(p2.getFullName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to modify the `Person` class to make it implement `Comparable`.

Instead you can write your own `Comparator` implementation which has the comparison method `compare(a, b)`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Collections.sort() has an overloaded version which takes the collection and comparator implementation to use.

```
public class NameCompartor implements Comparator<Person>{

@Override
public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return p1.getFullName().compareTo(p2.getFullName());
}

}


Collections.sort(personList, new NNameCompartor());
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are taking a subList.  Your sublist is skipping the first element (indexes are 0 based)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
class ComparatorPerson implements Comparator<Person>{
     public int compare(Person p1, Person p2){
            return p1.getFullName().compareTo(p2.getFullName());
     }
}
```

puis

```
 Collections.sort(subList, new ComparatorPerson());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a custom comparator first

```
private Comparator<Person> alphabetical = new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person left, Person right) {
        return left.getName().compareTo(right.getName());
    }
}
```

Then you can use the Collections.sort() method with 2 arguments

```
Collections.sort(peopleList, alphabetical);
```

Or since Java 8 you can use a Lambda

```
Collections.sort(people list, (left, right) -> left.getName().compareTo(right.getName()));
```